# Spring Data Neo4j is quite slow when importing

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

can somebody explain to me why it takes 6 to 10 seconds to import an entity into Neo4j?

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j with a custom Repository, that has `Neo4jTemplate @Autowire`-d. So when I'm persisting an entity I call `template.save(entity)`.
I do have to say though that the entity is a bit heavy. It has 47 properties, i.e. fields, 3 of them are marked with `@Indexed` annotation and 10 of them are other custom entities marked with `@RelatedTo`. 5 of the `@RelatedTo` fields are of type `Set`. Which means that actually when importing this one heavy entity another 10-15 entities could potentially also be persisted and connected to it.

Is that the actual problem or is there something I can do that could speed up the process?

I've looked around and found the `BatchInserter` but it doesn't take care of the indexes. I found [this](http://code.paananen.fi/2012/04/05/neo4j-batchinserter-and-spring-data-for-neo4j/) example implementation, but I would try it if there is no other other option.

So I guess what I'm trying to understand is, if the heavy entity is the reason for the slow persisting or something else.

I'm using Neo4j 1.8 and haven't touched the config files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
@Michael Hunger:
- The amount of data in the DB doesn't seem to have an effect.
- I'm not using AspectJ, so I guess I'm using simple mapping, right? Do you think I would get a better performance with AspectJ?
- I don't think I have an external transaction spanning the `save` method. I'm using the DB from a Wicket web application. Would it be better if I used Neo4j's REST API with for example *Jersey* REST clients?
- If there is an attribute in the class of a custom type, e.g. `Area area`, then another node will be automatically created for this `area` as well as a connection between the main node and the `area`, right? So there is no need for `template.createRelationshipBetween(entity1, entity2, type, properties, true)`, right? What I would have to do, to use this, is to remove the `area` attribute and then use some index to find the correct `area` and then make the connection manually. Is that what you meant?

This is how my **save** method looks like:

```
@Override
@Neo4jTransactional
public <T extends Identifiable> T save(T entity) {
    T saved = template.save(entity);
    Long savedId = saved.getId();
    Node savedNode = getNode(savedId);
    connectToContainerNode(savedNode, entity.getClass());

    return saved;
}
```

Here is an example of how entities are defined (ignore the @ExcelCell annotations). Usually there is an abstract class that is being extended by the persisted entity. Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

```
@NodeEntity
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public abstract class Building  implements Identifiable {
    @GraphId private Long id;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class, RefurbishedBuilding.class, ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=0, row=10)
    @Fetch

    private String concertoId;


    @Fetch
    @Indexed(indexName = "concertoUniqueId", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT) 
    private String concertoUniqueId;


    @Fetch
    @Indexed(indexName = "filename", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT) 
    private String filename;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=56),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=40),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=75),
    })
    @Fetch

    private Double floorAreaAccordingToLocalDefinition;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaCAP;


    @Fetch

    private HashMap formulaEFecmdirectMatrix;


    @Fetch

    private HashMap formulaEFecmindirectMatrix;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaEM;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaEN;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaIN;


    @Fetch

    private HashMap formulaINecaaMatrix;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaInvestmentAdditionalCosts;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaInvestmentTotalCosts;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=13),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=21),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=22),
    })
    @Fetch
    @Indexed(indexName = "name", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT) 
    private String name;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=55),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=39),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=74),
    })
    @Fetch

    private Double rentableArea;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=54),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=38),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=73),
    })
    @Fetch

    private Double totalCooledNetRoomArea;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=52),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=36),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=71),
    })
    @Fetch

    private Double totalGrossFloorArea;

    @ExcelCells({
    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=53),
    @ExcelCell( type={ReferenceBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=37),
    @ExcelCell( type={RefurbishedBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=72),
    })
    @Fetch

    private Double totalHeatedNetRoomArea;


    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "area", elementClass = Area.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Area area;

    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "community", elementClass = Community.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Community community;

    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "costsForTheEntireBuilding", elementClass = CostsForTheEntireBuilding.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private CostsForTheEntireBuilding costsForTheEntireBuilding;

    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "country", elementClass = Country.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Country country;

    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "project", elementClass = Project.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Project project;



    @RelatedTo(type = "costsForSelectedMeasuresOfBuilding", elementClass = CostsForSelectedMeasuresOfBuilding.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Set<CostsForSelectedMeasuresOfBuilding> costsForSelectedMeasuresOfBuilding = new LinkedHashSet<CostsForSelectedMeasuresOfBuilding>();


    @RelatedTo(type = "groupCostsOfBuildings", elementClass = GroupCostsOfBuilding.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Set<GroupCostsOfBuilding> groupCostsOfBuildings = new LinkedHashSet<GroupCostsOfBuilding>();


    @RelatedTo(type = "individualCostsOfBuilding", elementClass = IndividualCostsOfBuilding.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Set<IndividualCostsOfBuilding> individualCostsOfBuilding = new LinkedHashSet<IndividualCostsOfBuilding>();


    public Building(){}

    // getters and setters ommitted
}
```

And this is the NewBuilding class that extends the abstract Building class and that is persisted in the DB.

```
@NodeEntity

public class NewBuilding extends Building  {


    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=38)
    @Fetch

    private String applicableThresholdUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=38)
    @Fetch

    private String applicableThresholdValue;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1111})


    private AtticType atticType;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=67)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageEnergyTransmittanceOfWindowsAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=67)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageEnergyTransmittanceOfWindowsRealised;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=64)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCFacadeAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=64)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCFacadeBuildingEnvelopeSurfaces;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=64)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCFacadeRealised;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=65)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCGroundFloorAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=65)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCGroundFloorBuildingEnvelopeSurfaces;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=65)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCGroundFloorRealised;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=63)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCRoofAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=63)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCRoofBuildingEnvelopeSurfaces;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=63)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCRoofRealised;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=66)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCWindowsAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=66)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCWindowsFloorBuildingEnvelopeSurfaces;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=66)
    @Fetch

    private Double averageHTCWindowsFloorRealised;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1110})


    private BasementType basementType;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1636}, type={NewBuilding.class, })


    private BuildingIsOwnedOrRented buildingIsOwnedOrRented;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1635}, type={NewBuilding.class, })


    private BuildingIsPrivateOrPublic buildingIsPrivateOrPublic;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1112})


    private BuildingType buildingType;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForCoolingElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=11, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForCoolingNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForDomesticHotWaterElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=9, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForDomesticHotWaterNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForHeatingElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandForHeatingNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForCoolingElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=11, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForCoolingNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForDomesticHotWaterElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=9, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForDomesticHotWaterNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForHeatingElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForHeatingNonElectricity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=12, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double calculatedFinalEnergyDemandOfRefBuildingForLightingAndOther;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=20 ,textToIgnore="month/year")
    @Fetch

    private String completionDate;

    @ExcelCheckboxYesNo(sheet=1, yesId=1222, noId=1223)
    @Fetch

    private boolean contractingAgreementExists;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=40 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String contractingAgreementRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={751}, type={NewBuilding.class, })


    private DemonstrationActivityScheme demonstrationActivityScheme;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=2, sheet=5, row=11)
    @Fetch

    private Date endDateOfMonitoringPeriod;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandCoolingElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandCoolingElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=11, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandCoolingNonElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=11, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandCoolingNonElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandDomesticHotWaterElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandDomesticHotWaterElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=9, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandDomesticHotWaterNonElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=9, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandDomesticHotWaterNonElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandHeatingElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandHeatingElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandHeatingNonElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandHeatingNonElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=12, sheet=1, row=73)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandLightingAndAllOtherElectricityConcerto;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=12, sheet=1, row=72)
    @Fetch

    private Double energyDemandLightingAndAllOtherElectricityNational;

    @ExcelCheckboxYesNo(sheet=1, yesId=1188, noId=1189)
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyPerformanceCertificate;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1103})


    private EnergyPerformanceIndicatorRefersTo energyPerformanceIndicatorRefersTo;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=90 ,textToIgnore="specify capacity")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageCoolingCapacity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=90 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageCoolingRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={2024})


    private CapacityUnit energyStorageCoolingUnit;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={1375})
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyStorageCoolingUsed;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=89 ,textToIgnore="specify capacity")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageDHWCapacity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=89 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageDHWRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={2023})


    private CapacityUnit energyStorageDHWUnit;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={1371})
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyStorageDHWUsed;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=91 ,textToIgnore="specify capacity")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageElectricalCapacity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=91 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageElectricalRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={2025})


    private CapacityUnit energyStorageElectricalUnit;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={1469})
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyStorageElectricalUsed;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=88 ,textToIgnore="specify capacity")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageSpaceHeatingCapacity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=88 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageSpaceHeatingRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={2022})


    private CapacityUnit energyStorageSpaceHeatingUnit;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={1370})
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyStorageSpaceHeatingUsed;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=87 ,textToIgnore="specify capacity")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageThermalCapacity;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=87 ,textToIgnore="Remarks")
    @Fetch

    private String energyStorageThermalRemarks;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={2021})


    private CapacityUnit energyStorageThermalUnit;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={1367})
    @Fetch

    private boolean energyStorageThermalUsed;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaPEFec;


    @Fetch

    private Double formulaPEN;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={2041})
    @Fetch

    private boolean indicatorContainsCooling;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=35)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsCoolingUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=35)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsCoolingValue;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={2040})
    @Fetch

    private boolean indicatorContainsDomesticHotWaterProduction;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=34)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsDomesticHotWaterProductionUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=34)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsDomesticHotWaterProductionValue;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={2042})
    @Fetch

    private boolean indicatorContainsLighting;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=37)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsLightingUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=37)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsLightingValue;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={2039})
    @Fetch

    private boolean indicatorContainsSpaceHeating;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=33)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsSpaceHeatingUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=33)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsSpaceHeatingValue;

    @ExcelCheckbox(sheet=1, ids={2038})
    @Fetch

    private boolean indicatorContainsVentilation;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=36)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsVentilationUnit;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=36)
    @Fetch

    private String indicatorContainsVentilationValue;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=14)
    @Fetch

    private String location;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1101})


    private MainCharacteristicsOfCertificate1 mainCharacteristicsOfCertificate1;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1102})


    private MainCharacteristicsOfCertificate2 mainCharacteristicsOfCertificate2;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=21)
    @Fetch

    private String nameOfAppliedBuildingCode;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=27)
    @Fetch

    private String nameOfCertificate;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=24)
    @Fetch

    private String networks;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=48)
    @Fetch

    private String numberOfAppartmentsForResidentialBuilding;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=18)
    @Fetch

    private String numberOfBuildingsRepresentedByThisBuilding;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=49)
    @Fetch

    private String numberOfInhabitantsForResidentialBuilding;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=50)
    @Fetch

    private String numberOfOccupantsForNonResidentialBuilding;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=62)
    @Fetch

    private Double overallAverageHTCAccordingToRequirements;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=10, sheet=1, row=62)
    @Fetch

    private Double overallAverageHTCBuildingEnvelopeSurfaces;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=8, sheet=1, row=62)
    @Fetch

    private Double overallAverageHTCRealised;

    @ExcelDropdown(sheet=1, ids={1109})


    private PositionToNeighboringBuildings positionToNeighboringBuildings;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=23 ,textToIgnore="id of reference building")
    @Fetch

    private String referenceBuildingId;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=19 ,textToIgnore="month/year")
    @Fetch

    private String startDateOfConstructionWorks;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=2, sheet=5, row=10)
    @Fetch

    private Date startDateOfMonitoringPeriod;

    @ExcelCheckboxYesNo(sheet=1, yesId=1443, noId=1444)
    @Fetch

    private boolean totalDomesticGasConsumptionIncludesGasForCooking;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=58)
    @Fetch

    private Double totalGrossBuildingVolumeExternal;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=60)
    @Fetch

    private Double totalNetCooledVolumeInternal;

    @ExcelCell( type={NewBuilding.class}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=59)
    @Fetch

    private Double totalNetHeatedVolumeInternal;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=31)
    @Fetch

    private String unitOfIndicator;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=7, sheet=1, row=31)
    @Fetch

    private String valueOfIndicator;

    @ExcelCell( type={}, cell=6, sheet=1, row=22 ,textToIgnore="year")
    @Fetch

    private String yearOfPublicationOfAppliedBuildingCode;


    @ExcelRef
    @RelatedTo(type = "characterisationOfAppliedBuildingFeatures", elementClass = CharacterisationOfAppliedBuildingFeatures.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private CharacterisationOfAppliedBuildingFeatures characterisationOfAppliedBuildingFeatures;


    @ExcelCollection(type=BuildingEnergyService.class, start=0, end=5)
    @RelatedTo(type = "appliedEnergyServices", elementClass = BuildingEnergyService.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Set<BuildingEnergyService> appliedEnergyServices = new LinkedHashSet<BuildingEnergyService>();

    @ExcelCollection(type=MonitoringYearTotal.class, start=0, end=5, orientation=Orientation.SHEET)
    @RelatedTo(type = "monitoringYears", elementClass = MonitoringYearTotal.class, direction=Direction.BOTH)

    private Set<MonitoringYearTotal> monitoringYears = new LinkedHashSet<MonitoringYearTotal>();


    public NewBuilding(){}


    // getters and setters ommitted
}
```

Comment: making nodes with several properties (like in your case you have 47 properties) is a sign of a wrong database architecture. could you please give us an example of your graph db design?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ulkas. Probably to understand why there are 47 properties in one node I have to say that the node actually represents an excel file. So what is actually happening is that I take an excel file, parse it, create the node object with all those properties and persist it. Now you can imagine that this excel file has a lot of data to be parsed. So really I don't have a choice but to make this node really big. I think if I try to split it into separate objects it will take even longer because more nodes and connections have to be created rather than more key-value pairs.

Comment: but to give you an example:
I have an `abstract class A` which is extended by `class B`. `class B` has an `outgoing` 1:1 connection to `class C, D, E, F` and 1:n `outgoing` connection to `class G, H, I, J, K`. So `class B` represents one excel file. When I persist an object of `class B` I create a node that has an `incoming` connection to the reference node (0), and an `outgoing` connection to all nodes of type **B**.

Answer (score 0):

- Could you please share your entities or a sample project that exhibits the same behavior?
- How much data is already in your db?
- Do you use simple mapping or advanced mapping?
- Do you have an external transaction spanning the `save` method?
- I think your time is spent in handling the relationships (SDN does a duplicate check for each of those) can you try to replace those with `template.createRelationshipBetween(entity1, entity2, type, properties, true)` which skips those checks?

Comment: also, please turn off all indexes on those properties if any.